# clear button empties textarea but I cannot repopulate it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I am trying to create a web page where

1. if a user clicks on a word it is presented in a text box
2. if a word is clicked twice it does not appear again in the box
3. the user can clear the box with a button
4. the user can send the contents to another page

my code is the following:

```
<div id="parent">
    <!-- get the clicked word and add it to textarea-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#parent").delegate("span", "mousedown", function() {
            if ( $("#thediv").text().indexOf($(this).text()) <0 )
            {
                $("#thediv").append($(this).text());// get old div contents and add clicked word
                $("#thediv").append(' ');// also add a space
                $("#thediv").html(); //print to div
            };   
       })
    </script>

    <!-- clickable words  -->    
    <span>One </span><span>Two</span><span>Three</span>

    <!-- the form --> 
    <form action="/test/index6.html" method="get">
        <textarea id="thediv" name="thediv"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" >
    </form>

    <!-- Clear button  -->     
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#clear').click(function (){
            $("#thediv").val('');
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

it works fine, on mouseclick the word that is clicked is stored (if it is positioned between a  tag. for each word that is clicked, I check if the text area already contains it and if not i add it.

My problem is with the clear button. it clears the text area but then I cannot add any more words, as if this part of the code stops working.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `$("#thediv").val('');` to `$("#thediv").html('');`, as in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92sB6/).

Comment: btw, I have another question regarding another aspect of this code, namely how to put an (x) next to each word that allows me to remove it. does the stackoverflow etiquette require a new question or can I extend this one?

Comment: The best thing to do is to open a new question. I'd be happy to help you answer it, even :)